# How to create a Jest test for NgRx codes?

Tags: angular, jestjs, ngrx, ts-jest

I'm trying to write Jest tests but some codes are so difficult like NgRx codes where we do `store.dispatch` actions for example. I have searched for examples or Jest documents, video tutorials, ChatGPT and I realized that is not so easy to find docs about it. same of the examples failed on my tries. I just want to write a test for Actions and Select for now.

Here is a simple example:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class MyService
{
    constructor(
        private store: Store,

    ) {}
    startAction(){
        this.store.dispatch(MyActions.Action1());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without a specific question it's hard to answer the question.

That's why I refer you to the NgRx documentation that covers testing https://ngrx.io/guide/store/testing, or my own blog post about the same topic https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/testing-an-ngrx-project.

In short, there are several ways to test this using isolated unit tests on reducers/selectors/effects, unit tests on the component level using a mocked store, or an integration test for components using the real store instance.

Comment: Thankyou for the links, i'm reading this documentations, i hope i can do better. If i can make the tests i will share.